# Can a browser extension modify a webpage so that a blind person using it could access certain DOM element clicks using a keyboard?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a friend who is now totally blind, and asked me if there would be a way to play a card game that is played on HTML5 webpage.

He cannot click on the cards, so I was wondering how to program something client-side that could harvest the html/javascript data from the page, play audio files with card names when requested, and allow to select a card using keyboard movement (arrows), is Extensions the way to go?

Solutions that would work on only 1 browser are also wellcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using something like tampermonkey

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/

It's available for all browsers and would allow you to run the required javascript code as soon as they visited the site to add the extra functionality. You can include external scripts that would handle the keyboard presses such as :

https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap

Maybe if you post the site it would be easier to give more specific suggestions in regards to the DOM selection

Comment: Thanks, it is bridge-related sites, the most important are bridgebase.com and realbridge.online but it will take you a while to get there and be able to play.

Comment: bridgebase.com isn't very accessible friendly - ideally the cards would have a meta tag like "3-spade" but they have no distinguishing feature to identify them from code. The next best thing is the images used would be 3-spade.jpg to easily identify them, but they have them encoded as base64, you could still match the base64 string, it may need a little upkeep if they change the images though. Perhaps realbridge.online would have an easier setup to identify the cards, I didn't login to check. It could be done, but a bit of work :) Good Luck!

Comment: Hi Matt, just hope you can read this, I followed all your advice and I managed to finish a  working solution that is gonna help dozens of people with sight loss, so thank you.

Comment: That's awesome, Great job - I bet that was a ton of work, but such a worthwhile project.